# Error in python3 (TypeError: 'module' object is not callable)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyperclip

Im new to programming and im trying to make a simple program to replace something i copied with a string when its more than 10 characters long, this is the code:

```
import pyperclip
import tkinter as Tk
while True:
 r = Tk()
 r.withdraw()
 try:
      selection = r.selection.get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
 except tk.TclError:
      selection = None
      sleep(0.1)

 try:
     selection = r.selection.get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
 except tk.TclError:
     selection = None
     r.clipboard_clear()
     if len(result) > 10:
       pyperclip.copy("aaa")
```

But its giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
>>>
```

I understand this is probably related to the tkinter module but i dont really know what it is or how to solve it.

Comment: `Tk()` should be `Tk.Tk()`

Comment: it says line 2.

Comment: The first `Tk` is the module name, the second `Tk` is the class name.

Comment: i did that and now it says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2345, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'selection'

Comment: What is `r.selection` supposed to be? That's not a Tkinter attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call the `Tk` which is actually the alias for the `tkinter` module. What you would want to do in this case is:

```
r = Tk.Tk()
```

```
import pyperclip
import tkinter as Tk
while True:
 r = Tk.Tk()
 r.withdraw()
 try:
      selection = r.selection.get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
 except tk.TclError:
      selection = None
      sleep(0.1)

 try:
     selection = r.selection.get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
 except tk.TclError:
     selection = None
     r.clipboard_clear()
     if len(result) > 10:
       pyperclip.copy("aaa")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tk is a module, basically, it's tkinter module only that u called it in another name in your code. This is why you can't do `Tk()`.
You probably want to do something like:

```
r = Tk.NameOfClass()
```

or

```
from Tkinter import NameOfClass
```

Replace NameOfClass with the name of the class you want to use.